# Octave 'Load' called via C# much slower than when called via Octave CLI

Tags: c#, windows-7, octave

I am constructing a C#.Net program on a Win7 box, using Boroş Tiberiu's [Octave.cs class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342007/OctaveSharp-Running-GNU-Octave-with-Csharp) and Octave 4.0.1.  My program loads data from a text file with the lines

```
        cmdstr = "S = load (" + quote + "-ascii" + quote + ", " + quote + DatafilePathName + quote + ");";
        octave.ExecuteCommand(cmdstr);
```

which is equivalent to the Octave CLI command:

S = load ("-ascii", 'C:/Users/Frank/Documents/Octave/RemoveSel1.txt');

Execution of this line is nearly instantaneous when run from the Octave CLI, but takes around 7-8 seconds when run from the C# program, using the same datafile (about 2,000 records).

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: looks like your used lib communicates with GNU Octave through pipes so you have the overhead of Octvae printing to stdout and your lib reading and parsing the input from stdin.

Comment: Ah, I suspect you are correct.  I can live with the additional one-time delay, but I just wondered what was causing it.  Thanks for the informative reply

Comment: Btw, why are you using GNU Octave's "load" in C#? I think it would be faster if you load the file directly in C# or are you using cell and struct datatypes in the file?

Comment: Interesting point about direct file I/O in C# vs 'load' in Octave - I just hadn't thought about it.  I guess the real reason is that I constructed a script in Octave that did what I want, then called that script from C#.  The script contains the 'load' command, so I just left it there ;-).


Frank